# Pass Variable into jQuery Plugin Using Switch/Case

Tags: jquery, plugins, switch-statement

I am trying to pass the variable "starter" into a jQuery plugin as one of the config options.  The variable will be set using a switch statement where the variable is passed by clicking on an image with a specific id attribute.  If image id=1 then starter=1, etc.  Right now I'm able to set the variable and display it with an alert statement but don't seem to be able to pass it as a plugin parameter despite the switch statement returning the correct case.  What am I missing?  Thanks for your help!

```
     $(document).ready(function()
                    {
                        var starter = '2';
                        $("img").click(function(e){                         
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            switch ($(this).attr("id")) {                              
                                case "1": 
                                starter = 1;
                                break;                      
                                case "2": 
                                starter = 2;
                                break;
                                case "3": 
                                starter = 3; 
                                break;
                                case "4": 
                                starter = 4; 
                                break;
                                case "5": 
                                starter = 5; 
                                break;
                                case "6": 
                                starter = 6; 
                                break;
                            }
                          });
                        $("div").tinycarousel({
                            start: starter
                            });
                        $("img").click(function(){
                        alert(starter)
                       });
                          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
starter = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
```

Or maybe if 0 is a valid default case:

```
starter = $.isNumeric($(this).attr("id")) ? parseInt($(this).attr("id")) : 0;
```

Comment: Step over it in debugger.  Separate joined statements by doing things like putting `$(this).attr("id")` in a local variable and verifying it's correct. debug!